# Is there any use in the send parameter for XMLHttpRequests type GET?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm curious if I can use this parameter for anything useful.

It is for this code here: `xhr.send(param)`

```
var xhr;
if (config_ajax.type === 'get') {
    xhr = new win.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', config_ajax.url, true);
    // .. snip
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Here is the doc I checked.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing you can do with the parameter in a `GET` request. From [XMLHttpRequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send):

> If the request method is GET or HEAD, the argument is ignored and request body is set to null.

The argument is used if the method is `POST` or `PUT`.

You can write `xhr.send()` or `xhr.send(null)`, there's no difference.

Comment: so should I set it to null explicitly?  what is best practice?

Comment: I suspect `xhr.send()` is most common, but I have no evidence. Probably the vast majority of XHR requests use POST, not GET, except when using REST APIs.

Comment: I use Ajax GET to load all my files b.c. I'm loco

Answer (score -1):

You can send data via as an argument. From the docs:

`The best way to send binary content (like in files upload) is using an ArrayBufferView or Blobs in conjuncton with the send() method.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: But not with a `GET` request.

Comment: The web page you link to says that the argument is ignored when method = GET.

Comment: My mistake - looks like it just gets ignored.